Google Sheets : SUBTOTAL filter for non-SUBTOTAL function (such as RMS)
If I have a filter,  how can I perform functions which are not included in SUBTOTAL but still ignore hidden rows?
For example, condidering displayed data only, how can I perform a root mean square SUMSQ/COUNT or a MINIFS as to ignore blanks.
Is there a function to call the:

Range of non-hidden cells only?
Filter criteria of a column with a filter?


It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

try:
=LET(x, A1:A3, SUMSQ(FILTER(x, 1=BYROW(x, LAMBDA(x, SUBTOTAL(103, x))))))



